# How do I run a for loop in bash that would result in a parameter sweep?

Tags: python, bash

I am creating a simulation that contains a world, with an infected and uninfected population. In the simulation, I want to run a parameter sweep using bash to see all the results from various inputs.

The python file "diseaseSim_bash.py" takes in 10 command line arguments, where running:

```sh
python3 diseaseSim_bash.py V 100 5 7 7 5 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 > simulation1.txt
```

Would run the simulation using Von Neumann neighbourhoods, 100 Uninfected, 5 infected, a 7x7 grid (world), 5 Timesteps and probability of infection, immunity, death and recovery at 5% (0.05).

This works fine, producing the plots that I had created in the python file and saving them in the current folder. It also creates a text file for the outputs that are not images. When we get to the parameter sweep however, there's a bit of a challenge.

The bash file disease_sweep.sh contains code that creates a folder with a timestamp from when it was run, and copies the python file and the bash file into that folder for the purpose of the simulation. It also takes in command line arguments as follows:

```sh
sh disease_sweep.sh 80 120 5 2 20 2 0.02 0.20 0.02
```

This code makes the lower bound of the uninfected population 80, upper bound 120, going up in steps of 5 people. The lower bound of the infected population is 2, upper bound 20, step 2. Finally, the probability of being infected has  lower bound of 2%, upper bound 20%, step 2%.

There is code before the chunk I have inserted below that takes in these variables as command line arguments. I don't know if it is required, so I haven't included it for now. The code also prints out details regarding the command line input, ie.

```sh
echo "Bounds for Uninfected and step: " $low_pop $high_pop $step_pop
```

The reason I didn't provide the full code was because the above code runs fine, and gives me the output in my terminal. However, the next part seemingly doesn't provide any results.

```sh
for i in `seq $low_pop $high_pop $step_pop`;
do
    for d in `seq $low_inf $high_inf $step_inf`;
    do
        for x in `seq $low_prob $high_prob $step_prob`;
        do
            echo "Simulation: " $i $d $x
            outfile="Simulation_I"$i"_D"$d"_X"$x".txt"
            python3 diseaseSim_bash.py V $i $d 15 15 5 $x 0.05 0.05 0.05 > $outfile
        done
    done
done
```

By doing this, it should have saved all the text data into the outfile, and the images should have also been present in the folder, but this wasn't the case.

I'm wondering if there was an error in my for loop somewhere, something I might have glazed over. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you not getting errors due to the missing backticks?

Comment: Oops, my bad, it was in my code but I couldn't copy it over directly as it's running in my VM. The backticks are in the actual code - I will edit it now.

Comment: It's not the problem here, but in general, you should put double-quotes around variable references (or include them inside a double-quoted string. For example, `echo "Simulation:  $i $d $x"`, `outfile="Simulation_I${i}_D${d}_X${x}.txt"` (in this case, the `${}` is to make sure the following characters aren't mistaken for part of the variable name), and `python3 diseaseSim_bash.py V "$i" "$d" 15 15 5 "$x" 0.05 0.05 0.05 > "$outfile"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My `man` page for `seq` says this:

```
SYNOPSIS
       seq [OPTION]... LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
```

So if you want to provide a step width then that must be the *second* argument. In your code it seems you made it the last argument.

Indeed, `seq 2 5 1` produces an empty output while `seq 2 1 5` produces the numbers 2 through 5.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much for that! I think the reference I was using for the seq function was wrong (provided by a lecturer). This fixed the problem, thank you!